# resque scheduler upstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, upstart

I am trying to use resque scheduler but I could not find a good way to monitor the process.
What I want is to kill the scheduler job after any deploy and let `upstart` to restart it.
I wrote a capistrano script to kill the resque-scheduler

```
    task :stop_scheduler => :environment do
      pidfile = Rails.root + "tmp/pids/resque_scheduler.pid"
      if File.exists?(pidfile)
        pid = File.read(pidfile).to_i
        syscmd = "kill -s QUIT #{pid}"
        puts "Running syscmd: #{syscmd}"
        system(syscmd)
        FileUtils.rm_f(pidfile)
      else
        puts "****WARNING**** Scheduler pid file has not been found. Was scheduler running??"
     end
   end
```

At this point upstart will relaunch it.
My issue is probably with the upstart conf. I need Schduler to write PID in tmp/pids/resque_scheduler.pid to be able to kill it on the next restart.

Here is my upstart conf important parts:

```
respawn
respawn limit 99 5
console none

script
su -c "source 'cd /myapp/; RAILS_ENV={env} bundle exec rake resque:scheduler BACKGROUND=yes    PIDFILE=./tmp/pids/resque_scheduler.pid >> ~/resque_workers.log 2>&1" my_user
end script
```

Using this kind of conf I have the effect that the scheduler fork another time and the pid I have written on my pidfile is not correct.
I end with a process that continuously respawn and that I cannot kill anymore.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but have you checked out: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect

Basically, you need to tell upstart how many times to fork - in your case, I believe you would add `expect fork` to your upstart config file because su -c will fork once (you would use `expect daemon` if your script forked twice).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured out that I had to remove the BACKGROUND=yes flag.

I determined this by reviewing my fork count, which was more than 2 and just kept growing.  See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#how-to-establish-fork-count for info on how to do this.

I removed BACKGROUND=yes as a test and it worked.  I think this is because upstart automatically starts the task in the background and not only is instructing it to run in the background unnecessary, but it causes upstart to get confused and continually spawn new processes.

Once I removed BACKGROUND=yes, the result of the "how to establish fork count" referenced above was 2, meaning it's a daemon, and as such you'll need this in your upstart script:

expect daemon